# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop - REMOVE THIS WARNING WITHOUT ALTERING ARRAY

Tags: reactjs

Im learning react and got this issue . Saw an article which tells to give id, but since my data doesnt contain id, is there any other way to remove the warning. I dont want to modify the array :

```
<ul>
  {["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"].map(item =>
  <li>{item}</li>
  )}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do like this:

```
<ul>
  {["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"].map(item =>
  <li key={item}>{item}</li>
  )}
</ul>
```

Comment: @user8866 Welcome!, can you click solved?

Comment: Don't use index as key. This regularly causes bugs. You can use object identity as id: `<li key={item}>{item}</li>`